# SSL not working fine, Home url not matching with site url wordpress errors

Tags: ssl, site-url, home-url

I deployed WordPress through Bitnami so after adding an SSL certification I started getting warnings from my WordPress dashboard of my site URL not matching with Home URL I was directed to my WordPress settings To reset back to https://www.healthviewonfraweb.xyz instead of http but I saw that I could not do that on the my settings, I had to login my Myphpadmin to do it there but WP-OPTION still has the correct URL which is https://www.healthviewonfraweb.xyz but still not reflecting on my WordPress

My problem now is why is the URL on my WordPress General settings is http://www.healthviewonfraweb.xyz/ instead of https://www.healthviewonfraweb.xyz and still cannot be changed from there or why is the site URL on my wp-option not same with the one on my WordPress General settings.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of seeting the Site URL.

1. In the dashboard.
2. In the `wp-config.php` file.
3. In the `functions.php` file.

If you cannot change Option 1 above, then you should NOT edit the table in PhpMyAdmin.
Check for the following in wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

If you can't find that, then check in your functions.php for:

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

You can read more [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/)